# Why aren't cronjobs executed with python-crontab?

Tags: python, cron, ubuntu-16.04

I thought the following would execute `notify-send "Crontab Test"` every minute. But instead, it seems not to be executed at all:

### My Code

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from crontab import CronTab
cron = CronTab(user=True)

# List all cron jobs
for job in cron:
    print(job)


# Create new job
job = cron.new(command='/usr/bin/notify-send "Crontab Test"', comment='Crontab Test')
job.minute.every(1)

print("job.is_enabled()={}".format(job.is_enabled()))
print("job.is_valid()={}".format(job.is_valid()))

# Commit changes
cron.write()
```

### My System

- Ubuntu 16.04 (MATE), if I execute `notify-send "Crontab Test"` in bash it works
- `python-crontab==2.2.4` is installed

### The crontab file

```
$ cat /var/spool/cron/crontabs/math 
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - edit the master and reinstall.
# (/tmp/tmpdl3P0o installed on Thu Sep 14 10:26:28 2017)
# (Cron version -- $Id: crontab.c,v 2.13 1994/01/17 03:20:37 vixie Exp $)

* * * * * /usr/bin/notify-send "Crontab Test2" # Crontab Test2

* * * * * /usr/bin/notify-send "Crontab Test" # Crontab Test

* * * * * /usr/bin/notify-send "Crontab Test" # Crontab Test
```

Even changing the `notify-send` command to the absolute path of a self-written Python script (with the executable flag) which has no parameters did not work.

### Cron is running

```
$ service cron status 
● cron.service - Regular background program processing daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/cron.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Do 2017-09-14 09:08:08 CEST; 1h 22min ago
     Docs: man:cron(8)
 Main PID: 696 (cron)
    Tasks: 1
   Memory: 7.4M
      CPU: 949ms
   CGroup: /system.slice/cron.service
           └─696 /usr/sbin/cron -f
```

Logs:

```
$ grep cron /var/log/syslog
Sep 14 10:17:01 math-HP-EliteBook-Folio-1040-G3 CRON[25797]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Sep 14 10:20:25 math-HP-EliteBook-Folio-1040-G3 crontab[26516]: (math) LIST (math)
Sep 14 10:20:25 math-HP-EliteBook-Folio-1040-G3 crontab[26517]: (math) REPLACE (math)
Sep 14 10:21:01 math-HP-EliteBook-Folio-1040-G3 cron[696]: (math) RELOAD (crontabs/math)
Sep 14 10:26:28 math-HP-EliteBook-Folio-1040-G3 crontab[27919]: (math) LIST (math)
Sep 14 10:26:28 math-HP-EliteBook-Folio-1040-G3 crontab[27920]: (math) REPLACE (math)
Sep 14 10:27:01 math-HP-EliteBook-Folio-1040-G3 cron[696]: (math) RELOAD (crontabs/math)
```

crontab lists the commands:

```
$ crontab -l

* * * * * /usr/bin/notify-send "Crontab Test2" # Crontab Test2

* * * * * /usr/bin/notify-send "Crontab Test" # Crontab Test

* * * * * /usr/bin/notify-send "Crontab Test" # Crontab Test
```

Comment: this seems to be a script that just adds `* * * * * notify-send "Crontab Test" # Crontab Test` to user's crontab. check that (1) cron daemon is actually running (2) job is scheduled using `crontab -l` (3) change `notify-send` to the absolute path (.e.g `/usr/bin/notify-send`)

Comment: @ymonad I changed to the absolute path (which works fine in bash) and tried a couple of diagnostic commands (see question). It's still not working

Answer (score 0):

### The Problem

GUI programs don't work because `crontab` runs in background by default

### The Solution

I need to set the environment variable `DISPLAY=:0`, hence the command is

```
DISPLAY=:0 /usr/bin/notify-send "Crontab Test"
```

Comment:  - You came back to let us know that you solved it, and you left the solution!
⭐⭐⭐⭐⭐